# Как лучше осуществить влияние событий системы на объекты

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть система. Внутри нее есть объекты (летательные аппараты, наземные объекты, неподвижные объекты). Внутри системы происходят разные события, которые могут по разному влиять на эти объекты. Например, ветер меняет траекторию и скорость летательных аппаратов, но для наземных объектов меняет только скорость (в зависимости от направления движения объекта и ветра), на неподвижные совсем не влияет. Подскажите, какие паттерны тут лучше применить?

Answer (score 2):

Универсальных паттернов тут нет (во всяком случае названия мне не попадались), но общую концепцию модели, исходя из общей логики и как я ее себе представляю, можете посмотреть. Вероятно есть и другие варианты, но подозреваю, что отличия будут скорее декоративные.

Есть три типа объектов:

- активные
- пассивные
- глобальные

**Активные объекты** - это те, которые могут активно и избирательно взаимодействовать между собой и окружающими объектами. Активные объекты не обязаны быть подвижными, это вполне может быть здание командного центра осуществляющего мониторинг и координацию действий подчиненных объектов, сторожевая башня, отстреливающая приблудных орков, или Tesla Coil, если вы не любите орков =). Главное что эти объекты могут по собственной инициативе (заложенной в логику объекта, разумеется) взаимодействовать с другими объектами. Эти объекты могу произвольно добавляться и удаляться.

**Пассивные объекты** - не могут непосредственно влиять на окружающие объекты, но эти объекты или их свойства учитываются при взаимодействии с активными объектами (машина врезалась в столб, пассивный объект принимает непосредственное участие во взаимодействии с активным) или взаимодействии активных объектов между собой (один юнит прячется за стенкой, пока другой в него стреляет, пассивный объект принимает косвенное участие во взаимодействии активных). Эти объекты, в общем случае, тоже могу произвольно добавляться и удаляться.

**Глобальные объекты** - это объекты, которые могут оказывать влияние на все остальные объекты (освещение, ветер, туман, гравитация). Глобальные объекты, как правило, добавляются при создании общей модели и удаляются только вместе с ней, и могут менять свои свойства (отсутствие ветра не означает, что воздушные массы перестали двигаться, просто скорость их движения стала неощутимо малой; темнота - яркость источника света упала до нуля, но источник света при этом ни куда не делся). Не стоит делать глобальные объекты излишне сложными, оставьте только необходимое, или соберите несколько таких объектов в один, если у них есть общая логика (ветер, гроза и осадки могут быть собраны в объект погода).

Любой объект при расчете своих действий должен учитывать поправки на значения свойств глобальных объектов, от которых он зависит. Также у глобальных объектов могут быть события (поменялось направление/сила ветра, поменялась яркость освещения) или реализован интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` (раз уж речь про C#). Это удобно, когда глобальный объект оказывает влияние не постоянно (смена дня и ночи, направление и сила ветра), а точечно и/или разово в случайные моменты времени (удар молнии, землетрясение). На эти события подписываются объекты, которые могут от них зависеть (радио не работает во время грозы, землетрясение может разрушить постройки с малой прочностью).

Думаю для дальнейших размышлений информации достаточно, если что-то осталось не очень понятным, оставьте комментарий, постараюсь описать более детально.

Comment: Тут вопрос касается именно архитектуры. Буду оперировать вашей терминологией. Есть активные объекты разных типов. У них есть определенные свойства. Свойства меняются с течением времени по определенной формуле. Есть некоторые глобальные объекты (например, ветер). Глобальные объекты могут вмешиваться в определенные функции от времени (в вычисление значений некоторых свойств). Причем на одни типы объектов влиять одним образом, а на другие - другим. Влиять на скорость объекта типа А, но при этом не влиять на скорость объекта типа Б. Или влиять иначе (с другой зависимостью).

Comment: При этом и типы глобальных объектов и типы активных объектов могут добавляться. При этом расширение такое должно быть наименее болезненным.

Comment: @iRumba, Ок, я понял в какую сторону думать, к выходным дополню с учетом возможности расширения. Уточните только, что вы понимаете под "наименее болезненно", в общем то оно понятно, в идеале, чтобы вообще ничего делать было не надо кроме добавления новой сущности, но все таки. Под добавлением объектов я имел ввиду добавление в runtime, на этапе разработки любые объекты могут добавляться и удаляться.

Comment: Добавление я имел ввиду на этапе разработки. "наименее болезненно", значит это должно быть просто в плане разработки и поддержки (читаемости и количестве кода для добавления новых активных или глобальных объектов, наименьшей связности кода).